# Does a limit exist in a non-metrizable space?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, vector-spaces

Let $C$ be the vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0,1]$. And let $(C,\tau)$ be the topological vector space defined by the seminorms $$p_{x}(f)=|f(x)|~~~~(0\leq x\leq 1).$$ We have known that $(C,\tau)$ isn't metrizable, so, if $\{f_n\}\subset C$ lies in a neighborhood of  $f\in C$, can we say $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)?$$

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "if $\{f_n\} \subset C$ lies in a neighborhood of $f \in C$" mean? Why would you expect it to imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$? Are you asking whether convergence holds *for some* $x$, or *for all* $x$?

Comment: Limit is defined whenever there is a topology. We say $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ if and only if fix any neighborhood $V$ of $x$ there is an $N$ such that $x_n\in V$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: What I want to express is whether such a statement is correct:suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of $C$ such that $f(x)=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$ under the topology $\tau$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.Since $\tau$ is not metrizable,so there is not a metric on $C$,but the definition of limit depends on metrics.So I ask such a question.

Comment: A sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_x(f_n - f) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. You simply want convergence with respect to *all seminorms simultaneously*. Convergence of sequences is a topological concept. If a space is not metrizable then sequences may not be enough to *describe* the topology.

Comment: So the limit is defined in the sense of seminorms.Right?And what's your meaning of last sentence above?

Comment: If the space is metrizable then you can check whether a set is closed or if a function is continuous by using sequences. This need no longer be true if the space is not metrizable. There can be non-closed sets that are closed under taking limits of convergent sequences and there can be functions that are sequentially continuous but not continuous. See [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist;task=show_msg;msg=3738.0001) for a simple example in the topological setting.